# How can I find out which version of Qt Visual Studio Addin to install for different version of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, version, add-in

Different versions of the Qt Visual Studio Addin are available for download at

[Qt Visual Studio Addin](http://download.qt.io/archive/vsaddin/)

How do I know which version to install for different versions of Visual Studio?

I'm running Visual Studio 2012, but would like to know a general answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the archive by default, use it only if you need older version.
The Visual Studio addin you need depends on the Qt version you want, for Qt 5 you need version 1.2.4 and for Qt 4 you need 1.1.11, see the download section [here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-7)

Comment: Ok.  I tried version 1.2.4 for Qt5 with Visual Studio 2012, and it didn't work.  I saw in some post (don't recall where) that version 1.2.4 doesn't work with Visual Studio 2012, and to use version 1.2.3.  I will try version 1.2.4 again.

Comment: What was the problem?
There was a bug for 1.2.4 and VS2012 but it was fixed: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-392 Did you downloaded the addin now? If not re-download it now, else just use the archive to download 1.2.3

Comment: It was the same bug you pointed to that was "fixed."  After installing the addin version 1.2.4, when I start VS 2012, VS reports an error about "Qt Add-in 1.2.4 failed to load.  Would you like to remove this Addin?..."

Comment: I tried version 1.2.3. It didn't directly work. I tried to get it to work cleanly, but I have not succeeded. Closest I got is having to pasteqwindowsd.dll and qwindows.dll into Debug and Release .exe directories. I'm under impression that with correct value of `PATH` in Configuration Properties->Debugging Environment, that I can point VS to qwindowsd.dll.  However, seems like the vcxproj.user file is corrupted or corrupting the `PATH` value.  For instance, I see `PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3b$(VCRedistPaths)%PATH%
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)` after I set it to `PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin` and did a build/run.